# redis asp.net connection state provider connection issue

Tags: redis, asp.net-session

We are experiencing a large number of connections between asp.net and redis. During a 15 minute span we see connections ramp up to about 33,000 per second then slowly taper off after several hours.  We are using v2.0.1-Preview of the ASP.NET Session State Provider.

Comment: Thanks for information. So, did you have any question?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask good questions on SO.